# Partition Key in Azure

Tags: javascript, azure, windows-8

Is there any way to set the partition key of an item before inserting it using Javascript?

I've got a Win8 JS app and I want to set the PK so I can have several Cars (for example) linked to an User to be able to given an username, I can query every car that belongs to it. Also, for performance stuff, these Cars should be in the same partition, so, any way?

For example, let's say I've got an User. An User can have several properties, among them, a list of Cars. I've got two tables in Azure Table Storage, one for users and another one for cars and I want to link cars to users through User property "username" (a string) in such a way that I can create a query to select cars whose id is "username".  I also want to have performance issues into account so I find desirable to have each set of cars in its own partition asigning them as PK user's username. The question is how can I do this in W8JS app.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit I am finding your description hard to follow.

Comment: I've edited the original question

Comment: partitionkey is just another field that you'd apply in your update - not sure where you're stuck?  What code are you using now to update say the Cars table?

Comment: also to add to what @JimO'Neil is asking.  What data are you using for partition and row keys in both tables?

Comment: Have a GUID as a username or make a logic to ensure the username as unique. Using the username as partition key, you can solve your problem.